# How to pass extra arguments to callback register functions with twisted python api?

Tags: python, twisted

I have the following python code using the twisted API.

```
def function(self,filename):    
    def results(result):
       //do something
    for i in range(int(numbers)) :
        name = something that has to do with the value of i         
        df = function_which_returns_a defer(name)
        df.addCallback(results)
```

It uses the Twisted API. What i want to achieve is to pass to the callbacked function (results) the value of the name which is constructed in every iteration without changing the content of the functions_which_returns_a defer() function along with the deferred object of course. In every result of the functions_which_returns_a deffer the value of the name should be passed to results() to do something with this. I.e: at the first iteration when the execution reach the results function i need the function hold the result of the deffered object along with the value of name when i=0,then when i=1 the defered object will be passed with the value of name, and so on.So i need every time the result of the defer object when called with the name variable alond with the name variable. When i try to directly use the value of nameinside results() it holds always the value of the last iteration which is rationale, since function_which_returns_a defer(name) has not returned.

Comment: For the general case see [callback - Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter). In this specific case (twisted library) the solution below is better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass extra arguments to a `Deferred` callback at the `Deferred.addCallback` call site by simply passing those arguments to `Deferred.addCallback`:

```
def function(self,filename):    
    def results(result, name):
       # do something
    for i in range(int(numbers)) :
        name = something that has to do with the value of i         
        df = function_which_returns_a defer(name)
        df.addCallback(results, name)
```

You can also pass arguments by keyword:

```
        df.addCallback(results, name=name)
```

All arguments passed like this to `addCallback` (or `addErrback`) are passed on to the callback function.