# Finding the argument of a parent function from a callback

Tags: python, callback, pyaudio

How can I find the argument given to a function that's calling a `callback` function, from within the `callback`?

The below code (incomplete) will initiate an audio stream that calls a callback function. It uses pyaudio.

Right now, there are hard-coded stuff in the `callback` function. I'm trying to get rid of those.

I've read the pyaudio doc and I can't seem to be able to pass extra arguments to the `callback` function. I've read about the `inspect` python module, its `getsource` or `getouterframes` that seemed to be interesting for me, in order to hopefully get to the argument given to the `PlayStream` function, but that has led me nowhere.

How can I refer to the `SoundGeneratorObject` argument from within `callback`?

```
def PlayStream(SoundGeneratorObject):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(SoundGeneratorObject.WIDTH), 
                 channels = SoundGeneratorObject.CHANNELS, 
                 rate = SoundGeneratorObject.BITRATE, 
                 frames_per_buffer = SoundGeneratorObject.CHUNKSIZE,
                 output = True,
                 stream_callback = callback)
    stream.start_stream()
    while stream.is_active():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
    signal = waves.next()
    return (signal, pyaudio.paContinue)

waves = SoundGenerator()
PlayStream(waves)
```

Comment: Have you considered naming `SoundgeneratorObject` -> `sound_generator_object` when it is an argument? I got confused there :)

Comment: You can pick any convention as long as you **keep** it and not change back and forth :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do something like this to create a scope for the callback you're passing?

```
def callback_maker(waves):
    def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
        # do stuff (waves is in scope)
        signal = waves.next()
        return (signal, pyaudio.paContinue)
    return callback
```

If you can, use it like this:

```
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(SoundGeneratorObject.WIDTH), 
                channels = SoundGeneratorObject.CHANNELS, 
                rate = SoundGeneratorObject.BITRATE, 
                frames_per_buffer = SoundGeneratorObject.CHUNKSIZE,
                output = True,
                stream_callback = callback_maker(SoundGeneratorObject))
```

Comment: Well, actually, 1 question: the callback_maker only takes 1 argument, but pyaudio is very rigid about the arguments required for the callback function. How are arguments passed from pyaudio to the nested callback function?

Comment: @grabaldam You're actually **activating** the function `callback_maker` with the argument `waves`, which returns a callback **function**. That's why it's called callback maker :-) . The function that's returned is then passed as the callback, but it has `waves` in it's scope (the one that was received in `callback_maker`).

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer has been accepted, I'd like to show an alternative as how technically you can access the argument from parent function by using **inspect** and **globals()**, this sample will work:

```
import inspect

# as argument
SoundGeneratorObject = 'Hello World'

def PlayStream(SoundGeneratorObject):
    a, b, c = 8, 9, 10
    print "do a callback"
    callback(a, b, c)

def callback(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c
    # inspect.stack[1][3] can get the function name that called the callback
    # inner globals then access to the function by its name
    # func_code.co_varnames will then get the argument name from the function
    # since you only have 1 argument, that's why I use index [0]
    # the outer globals will then access the argument value by its name
    print globals()[globals()[inspect.stack()[1][3]].func_code.co_varnames[0]]

# call the parent function
PlayStream(SoundGeneratorObject)

do a callback
8 9 10
Hello World # successfully get the argument value
```