# In Python, how do I pass parameters in a threaded callback?

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, parameter-passing

Basically I am watching logic levels for some sort of change and then timing how long that lasts.  Since I have many different lines to watch, I started to create a function for each line.  So I thought, why don't I just create one function that uses different parameters depending on the line that gets triggered.

```
def myCallBack(pin, bool, Ftimer, Etimer):
    ## some more code here for checking bools and using timers

GPIO.add_event_detect(pin1, GPIO.both, callback=myCallBack(pin1, bool1, Ftimer1, Etimer1), bouncetime=200)
GPIO.add_event_detect(pin2, GPIO.both, callback=myCallBack(pin2, bool2, Ftimer2, Etimer2), bouncetime=200)
...
```

Currently, I am getting the error "TypeError: Parameter must be callable"
Is this approach even possible?  Am I going about this the right way?
Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this fixes my problem, but it does work.  I created a class to make objects since I am doing the same set of functions on each logic line.  I found this [stackoverflow link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27939/using-a-class-function-as-callback-with-gpio-add-event-detect) and followed the same pattern.  This works just fine for what I need to get done.

Answer (score 5):

```
from functools import partial
callback=partial(myCallBack, pin1, bool1, Ftimer1, Etimer1)
```

This will produce a function without arguments, that calls `myCallBack` with `pin1`, `bool1`, `Ftimer1` and `Etimer1` when called. Alternatively, try:

```
callback=lambda *a: myCallBack(pin1, bool1, Ftimer1, Etimer1)
```

Also see [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter).

Comment: I am still getting 'TypeError: Parameter must be callable'
I did some more digging into Partial and found that you can add arguments either when you create the partial object or when you call it. Either way I still get errors.
If I just call the myCallBack, it will run the function just fine.  It seems to have a problem when I call it from within GPIO.add_event_detect

Comment: @MattMumm Could you try the second method above?

Comment: Sorry I missed that for some reason.
Just tried it and it has the same reaction as the first method you suggested.

Comment: @MattMumm Is myCallBack a function? Could you add a full traceback to the question.