# Passing variable to SplashRequest callback function in Scrapy

Tags: python, variables, callback, scrapy, splash-screen

I have a mini project where there is a list of URLs on the first page and then I have to follow each URL in these list of URLs and open each URL with SplashRequest because I need the returned page to be rendered along with its JavaScript component.

Now, I'm very new to all of these web scraping and **scrapy-splash** but basically I'm currently stuck because I'm trying to figure out how to pass a variable to the callback function when using **SplashRequest**. Basically, I have no idea how to pass a variable to our callback function below:

```
  yield SplashRequest(url=someUrl,callback=theCallBackFunction,args={
               //some args
            })
```

I know that for normal Scrapy without Splash, we can just say

```
yield response.follow(url=someUrl,callback=theCallBackFunction,meta={
     //some variables we want to pass to callback function
}
```

but I don't know how to do it with Scrapy-Splash.

So yeah, looking for help from anyone who's more experience in this area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252201/passing-a-argument-to-a-callback-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this one myself, apparently the SplashRequest also takes **meta** as its argument just like **response.follow** so the mechanism of passing variables to the callback function is exactly the same as using a normal scrapy.