# Run a sync sequence of commands in sublime plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've been trying to write a very simple plugin for Sublime Text (3) but being new to the topic either I am missing something or something is not working as expected.

I want to create a command that move the current tab to a specified group (for example group 0 for simplification). Right after that I want to focus on that group:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MoveAndFocusToGroupCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("move_to_group",{"group": 0})
        self.window.run_command("focus_group", {"group": 0})
```

The previous snippet does **not** work. The first command will be executed but not the second one.
If I comment the first command, then the second one is executed.

Maybe the commands are executed on different threads or something async is going on.

I've also tried to run the second command in an event handler:

```
class MoveAndFocusToGroupCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):

    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("move_to_group",{"group": 0})

class MovedToGroupEventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_post_window_command(self, window, name, args):
        if name == 'move_to_group' and args is not None:
            window.run_command("focus_group", args)
```

but nothing changes, the focus will never set on group 0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The first command should also set the focus to the group. If the group is empty after the movement it seems to create a view, which graps the focus after you executed your commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial code worked fine for me, until I tried it on the last remaining view in the second group.

As [**r-stein**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5963435/r-stein) mentioned in the comments, it seems that the blank view created by SublimeText in the empty group is interfering with the timing of your command sequence.

The following code uses `set_timeout_async` to re-sequence the order of commands. I omitted the optional `delay` parameter, as it seems to work fine without it.

---

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MoveAndFocusToGroupCommand( sublime_plugin.WindowCommand ):

    def run( self ):
        self.window.run_command( "move_to_group", { "group": 0 } )
        sublime.set_timeout_async( lambda: self.window.focus_group( 0 ) )
```

Comment: if you are aware of it, is this a sort of bug or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: btw I had to add a small delay to this, because sometimes things were not 100% predictable `sublime.set_timeout_async(lambda: self.focus(group), 200)`. It turns out the plugin TabsExtra interferes in this, but setting a delay of 200ms fixed everything.

Comment: Why has `lambda:` been used in the call to `set_timeout_async()`? It seems unnecessary to me and the plugin works fine without it, but am I missing some subtle reason for its use? I've only used *lambda functions* when creating *anonymous functions* in Python, e.g. `map(lambda x: x**2, num_list)` which uses a *lambda function* instead of a pre-defined function e.g. `map(calc_square, num_list)` and I've not seen `lambda:` used in conjunction with a pre-defined function before nor without at least one argument.

Comment: @mattst I guess without arguments we could omit lambda and just pass `self.focus` but in my case it's useful because I'm passing an argument to self.focus so it acts as a wrapper

Comment: @Leonardo @Enteleform All of the following work fine in Enteleform's plugin: `set_timeout_async(self.focus)`, `set_timeout_async(self.focus, 200)`, `set_timeout_async(self.focus(group_num))`, `set_timeout_async(self.focus(group_num), 200)` assuming `focus()` is defined to take a group number parameter i.e. `def focus(self, group_num)` when needed. So the wrapper is not necessary. I'd be interested to hear if Enteleform had another reason for using a *lambda function*?

Comment: @mattst: I'm still pretty new to working with threads & lambdas; so I don't entirely understand how they work yet. Keith Hall previously helped me out with [**His Answer**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/retrieving-inserted-and-deleted-text/18697/23) to [**This Question**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/retrieving-inserted-and-deleted-text/18697/20), but it looks like I misused his method in the first draft of this answer. After reviewing his explanation again, I implemented his method directly on `self.window.focus_group` and removed the additional `WindowCommand` function.

Comment: @Leonardo: I don't think it's a bug, it just seems like ST's creation of a placeholder view is happening after `move_to_group` occurs in a group with only 1 view. I'm guessing that happens immediately, which is why the `set_timeout` function is successful in this solution - it allows `focus_group` to occur *after* the placeholder view has been created.

Comment: @Enteleform `sublime.set_timeout_async( lambda: self.window.focus_group( 0 ) )` is better, but it works fine without the `lambda:` bit. In Keith's answer he does not use a *lambda function*, he uses a *nested function*, a function defined within a function. In Python a *lambda function* is a way to create an *anonymous function*, the `lambda x: expr` notation can be used in any place that would usually expect a pre-defined function. `set_timeout_async` is expecting a function in its first parameter, `lambda` can be used instead of, but not as well as (though clearly the syntax is allowed).

Comment: @Enteleform @Leonardo Thinking about it I'd say the `lambda:` in `sublime.set_timeout_async(lambda: self.window.focus_group(0))` either does absolutely nothing at all, or it serves as a totally unnecessary wrapper. Probably the latter, but my Python isn't good enough to know which. Anyone?

Comment: @mattst: From my understanding of Keith's explanation, callbacks, and the `set_timeout` function; the first parameter of `set_timeout` should be a callback in the format `functionName` as opposed to `functionName()`. If using the latter variant, the function will be executed immediately rather than called back. Since `focus_group` requires an argument, it must be enclosed within a `lambda` ( *or* `partial` ). Here is a [**related answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter) on using callbacks with arguments.

Comment: @Enteleform Thanks. That's the subtlety that I was missing. Using a parameter without using `lambda` in the call to `set_timeout_async` results in apparently working code but the timeout doesn't actually happen. On my system that didn't matter, the code worked with or without the timeout, resulting in my confusion. Glad to have it all clear in my mind now. Cheers.