# How should I connect CheckBox clicked signals in Table Widgets in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I would like to add various widgets to various cells in a Table Widget, and I would like to trigger commands when those widgets' values are changed. I can get the widgets into the table as desired, but I'm having problems connecting signals so that I know which widget has generated the signal.

Below is a simple example explaining the problem, using just checkboxes:

[image: Screenshot: TableWidget, CheckBoxes]

```python
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create table:
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        [self.table.insertRow(i) for i in [0,1,2]]
        [self.table.insertColumn(i) for i in [0,1]]
        # set values for first column:
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('A') )
        self.table.setItem(1, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('B') )
        self.table.setItem(2, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('C') )
        # add checkboxes to second column:
        cb0  = QtWidgets.QCheckBox( parent=self.table )
        cb1  = QtWidgets.QCheckBox( parent=self.table )
        cb2  = QtWidgets.QCheckBox( parent=self.table )
        self.table.setCellWidget(0, 1, cb0)
        self.table.setCellWidget(1, 1, cb1)
        self.table.setCellWidget(2, 1, cb2)
        # connect table signals:
        self.table.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)
        self.table.itemChanged.connect(self.item_changed)
        # connect checkbox signals:
        cb0.clicked.connect(self.checkbox_clicked)
        cb1.clicked.connect(self.checkbox_clicked)
        cb2.clicked.connect(self.checkbox_clicked)
        # show:
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle('TableWidget, CheckBoxes')
        self.show()

    def cell_changed(self, row, col):
        print(row, col)
    def checkbox_clicked(self, checked):
        print(checked)
    def item_changed(self, item):
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    app.exec_()
```

Based on `table.cellChanged.connect` I would naively expect a `cellChanged` signal when the checkboxes are changed.  However this signal is not generated. Nor is the `itemChanged` signal.  I can indeed see the `clicked` signals, but that is not very useful because it is unclear which checkbox has produced the signal.

One way to solve the problem is to create a different `checkbox_clicked` function for each checkbox, but that hardly seems elegant.

My questions are:

1. Why is neither a `cellChanged` nor an `itemChanged` signal generated when a checkbox is changed?
2. How should signals be connected in order to know which checkbox has generated the `clicked` signal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Why is neither a cellChanged nor an itemChanged signal generated when
>      a checkbox is changed?

because when you use `setCellWidget()` a `QTableWidgetItem` is not created, and if we check the documentation of [`cellChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellChanged) and [`itemChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged):

> **void QTableWidget::cellChanged(int row, int column)**
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the data of the **item** in the cell specified by row and column has changed.
>
> **void QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *item)**
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the data of **item** has changed.

---

> 2. How should signals be connected in order to know which checkbox has generated the clicked signal?

The way to obtain is indirectly, the first thing to know is that when the widget is added through the `setCellWidget()` method, the `viewport()` of the `QTableWidget` is set as a parent.

Also another thing that should be known is that the position of a widget that is accessed through `pos()` is relative to the parent, that is, in our case relative to `viewport()`.

There is a very useful method called `sender()` that returns the object that emits the signal, in this case it will return the `QCheckBox`.

As the position of the widget with respect to the `viewport()` is known, its `QModelIndex` is accessed through the [`indexAt()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt) method, the `QModelIndex` has the information of the cell.

All of the above is implemented in the following example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create table:
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(3)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        for i, letter in enumerate("ABC"):
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(letter))
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            ch = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(parent=self.table)
            ch.clicked.connect(self.onStateChanged)
            self.table.setCellWidget(i, 1, ch)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle('TableWidget, CheckBoxes')
        self.show()

    def onStateChanged(self):
        ch = self.sender()
        print(ch.parent())
        ix = self.table.indexAt(ch.pos())
        print(ix.row(), ix.column(), ch.isChecked())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Another way to do it is through lambda methods or partial.functions where we pass directly new parameters.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create table:
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(3)
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        for i, letter in enumerate("ABC"):
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(letter))
        for i in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            ch = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(parent=self.table)
            ch.clicked.connect(lambda checked, row=1, col=i: self.onStateChanged(checked, row, col))
            self.table.setCellWidget(i, 1, ch)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle('TableWidget, CheckBoxes')
        self.show()

    def onStateChanged(self, checked, row, column):
        print(checked, row, column)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to know more information how to pass extra parameters through connect() you can review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091180/6622587).

Comment: I actually did read the documentation, but I was quite confused by the statement: "...whenever the data of the **item**... has changed."  It seems that an added widget is also an item. It would be much clearer if it said  "...whenever the data of the QTableWidgetItem... has changed.  The signal is not emitted for cells into which other widgets have been added using the setCellWidget method".

Comment: An item is different from a widget, when in the documentation it refers to an item it is understood as QTableWidgetItem. :P

Comment: @user2269232 The issue is that there are many widgets that can be added to QTableWidget, and each widget has its own signals and events, so making a generic code that maps all those fields is impossible, instead a QTableWidgetItem is a custom class to work with QTableWidget and therefore the methods and signals are known.

Comment: Perfectly clear now, thank you!  I prefer the **lambda** method you suggested for this simple case where I just need rows and columns.  I can see how the **sender()** method can be generally quite useful.  Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

use the `stateChanged` signal for checkboxes.

and my take about that code:

- in some cases it's helpful to have a reference to checkbox widgets, for some logic actions.
- use loops if possible
- use explicit imports in PyQt - the class names are unique and it's more readable

for example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTableWidgetItem, QCheckBox, QApplication
from typing import Dict

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # create table:
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.insertColumn(0)
        self.table.insertColumn(1)
        self._items: Dict[QTableWidgetItem, QCheckBox] = {}
        for i, tag in enumerate(['A', 'B', 'C']):
            self.table.insertRow(i)
            item = QTableWidgetItem(tag)
            cb = QCheckBox(parent=self.table)
            self._items[item] = cb
            # set values for first column:
            self.table.setItem(i, 0, item)
            # add checkboxes to second column:
            self.table.setCellWidget(i, 1, cb)
            # connect cb signals:
            self._items[item].stateChanged.connect(self.checkbox_clicked)
        # connect table signals:
        self.table.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)
        # show:
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)
        self.setWindowTitle('TableWidget, CheckBoxes')
        self.show()

    def cell_changed(self, row, col):
        print(row, col)
    def checkbox_clicked(self, checked):
        print(checked)
    def item_changed(self, item):
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    app.exec_()
```