# How to get the QModelIndex associated with the QCheckbox placed in the QTableWIdget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the following code to place a CheckBox in the first column of a list of items in a QTableWidget.

```
checkboxWidget = QWidget()
checkBox = QCheckBox(checkboxWidget)
checkBox.clicked.connect(self._check_changed)
#
#   If the variable is in the monitored list
#   check the checkbox
#
isMonitored = False
if (self._monitored_variables != None):
    if (self._monitored_variables[name]):
        isMonitored = True
if (isMonitored):
    checkBox.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Checked)
else:
    checkBox.setCheckState(Qt.CheckState.Unchecked)

layoutCheckbox = QHBoxLayout(checkboxWidget)
layoutCheckbox.addWidget(checkBox)
layoutCheckbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
layoutCheckbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
self._variables_view.setCellWidget(row,0, checkboxWidget)
```

I started with the answer to this question:
[How should I connect CheckBox clicked signals in Table Widgets in PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057638/how-should-i-connect-checkbox-clicked-signals-in-table-widgets-in-pyqt5)

The difference that I have is that I want the CheckBox centered in the table cell, hence the extra controls.

The click handler looks like this:

```
 def _check_changed(self):
    cb = self.sender()
    print(cb.parent())
    ix = self._variables_view.indexAt(cb.pos())
    print(ix.row(), ix.column(), cb.isChecked())
```

The problem I am facing is that the row/column is not correct.

How can I recover the row/column of the CheckBox that was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>It seems that my previous answer was not explicit but I am going to take this answer to take it in a generic way that will work for all the classes that inherit from QAbstractItemView and any type of widget placed through the setCellWidget or setIndexWidget methods.</sub>

#### General case:

The key to the solution is to obtain the position of the widget that emits the signal with respect to the viewport of the QAbstractItemView, and then use indexAt to get the QModelIndex. This can be obtained by following the following steps:

1. Map any relative internal position of the widget to global coordinates.
2. Map global coordinates to local coordinate relative to the viewport.
3. use indexAt() with local coordinate.

   ```py
   gl = widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint())
   lp = view.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
   ix = view.indexAt(lp)
   ```

---

#### Specific case:

In this case, just do the following:

```
def _check_changed(self):
    widget = self.sender()
    gl = widget.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint())
    lp = self._variables_view.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
    ix = self._variables_view.indexAt(lp)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to my issues was rather simple. In the "indexAt" method the "cb.pos()" needs to be changed to "cb.parent().pos()".