# pyqt4: connect a slider to refresh a plot

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to design a GUI to refresh a plot i.e. `plot(timeS, dataS)`, using a slider corresponding to the time vector (`timeS`) of the data that I want to display (`dataS`) which is varying in time.

I have tried to connect the slider to my plot function which has a lot of input
`self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.myPlotFunction(.....))`, which is located in the init part of my class, but I can't use the input of the defined function `myPlotFunction()`.

So I want that when I start dragging the slider, the plot changes according to the time/position of the slider. Moreover my time vector is made of floats while the slider allows int values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing extra arguments through connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090982/passing-extra-arguments-through-connect)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a slot, you don't call the function, so

```
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.myPlotFunction(.....))
```

should look like

```
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.myPlotFunction)
```

and your definition of `myPlotFunction` must match the argument signature of the `valueChanged` signal, so

```
def myPlotFunction(self, sliderValue):
    # Do stuff
    pass
```

If you need to pass more stuff to `myPlotFunction`, you can use a lambda, making sure to accomodate the arguments that Qt will pass first, i.e.

```
otherVar = "some other stuff"
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda sv, ov=otherVar: self.myPlotFunction(sv, ov))
```

and adjust the definition of `myPlotFunction` accordingly.