# Getting and Passing the last QKeyEvent raised in PyQt5 through textChanged Connection

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-connection

Hello I am using PyQt5 `QTextEdit()` and I want to bind the `textChanged()` to `self._backspaceissue()`
where `self._backspaceissue()` is defined as:

```
@pyqtSlot(QKeyEvent)
def _backspaceissue(self,event):...
```

I saw this question and thought it may apply but I don't understand any of the functionality behind it so I am not fully sure if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090982/passing-extra-arguments-through-connect

This mentions using `functools.partial()` or `lambda` but I don't see how that could work.
Though before we can do this is there a way to get the QKeyEvent that caused the textChanged?

I have tried looking into the `__dir__` of the QTextEdit and found nothing of use and no documentation over it

EDIT:
I will add my code for `_backspaceissue()` and `keyPressEvent()`:

```
@pyqySlot(QKeyEvent)
def _backspaceissue(self,event):
        try:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backspace:
                if self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1] == '' or self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1] in self.disallowed_deletes:pass
                else:super().keyPressEvent(event)
            else:super().keyPressEvent(event)
        except AttributeError:pass
def keyPressEvent(self, e) -> None:
    a=QTextCursor(self.document())
    self.last_event=e
    match e.key():
        case Qt.Key_Backspace:
            #check if line is empty and if so do nothing else remove the last character
            print("Backspace hit: TEXT="+self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1])
            if self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1] == '' or self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1] in self.disallowed_deletes:pass
            else:super().keyPressEvent(e)
        case Qt.Key_Return:
            #take the line of text and push it up one line and print the output in the current line then display the next input
            self.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
            print(f"Enter hit: TEXT="+self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1])
            final_output=self._handleCommand(self.toPlainText().split('\n')[-1].removeprefix(self.prefix))
            self.insertHtml('<br>' + final_output + f'<br>{self.prefix}')
        case _:super().keyPressEvent(e)
```

I wanted to use something like this:

```
self.textChanged.connect(partial(self._backspaceIssue, self.last_event))
```

Comment: You could do that within a `keyPressEvent()` override, but that would only work partially, as you'd need to check if the event actually causes a text change, and this doesn't cover usage of clipboard actions. Can you explain what you're actually trying to do and what that `_backspaceissue()` does?

Comment: It is meant to be a command prompt and QTextEdit doesn't support partial readonly based on certain strings so I was trying to use `keyPressEvent()` to not allow backspacing on the text if it was the prefix I didn't wanna delete but the keyPressEvent will allow the user to hold backspace and that will not correctly update the string used to evaluate if the user can backspace any further.  `_backspaceissue()` was supposed to be my next attempt at fixing this using the textChanged signal

Comment: If you want to prevent backspace actions, interacting with a `textChanged` signal is certainly not a good choice: at that point, text has already changed, and trying to "restore" it is not only unreliable, but also unacceptable. Overriding the `keyPressEvent()` *may* work, but you need to check for key event types, and that could be very tricky, especially for non-latin characters or clipboard interaction. You have to consider that command prompts are not just "text editors", they are a virtual representation of a real prompt, which requires more complex levels of output/key event handling.

Comment: would there be a way of implementing this in pyQt5