# Wrap callback function to include extra argument when caller verifies exact callback signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I'm trying to bind multiple callback functions across multiple properties with code that looks something like:

```
for key in keys:
    def callback(self, value):
        #Do stuff...
        return None

    doSomething(callback)
```

This works because the calling code (that calls `callback`) expect *exactly* two parameters and the `callback` to return `None`. The issue is now I want to wrap the callback such that I can also pass the `key` in something like:

```
for key in keys:
    def wrappedCallback(self, value):
        #How do I get key in here???
        realCallback(self, key, value)
        return None

    doSomething(wrapperCallback)
```

But I have no idea how to get key inside of wrapperCallback. I can't add an extra default parameter like:

```
...
#This throws with "expected a function taking 2 arguments, not 3"
def wrappedCallback(self, value, key=key):
    realCallback(self, key, value)
    ...
```

because this will throw an error from the caller (it's C code that expects a very strict callback). I've also tried `functools.partial` but then I get `expected a function, not a functools.partial`

How do I wrap the passed callback function to include the external parameter `key` (from the for loop) while keeping the *exact* signature described?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a callback generator that takes your parameters (such as `key`) and creates your callbacks.

```
>>> def callback_generator(key):
...     def callback(self, value):
...         do_something_with(key, value)
...     return callback
...
>>> for key in keys:
...     doSomething(callback_generator(key))
...
```

Comment: I like this better because at least it's outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Minutes after I figured out that I can create a function inside the for loop to get a new stack frame. This unfortunately does not seem at all Pythonic...

```
for key in keys:
    def dummyForStackFrame(key): #Extra function to get a new stack frame with key
        def wrappedCallback(self, value):
            realCallback(self, key, value)
            return None
        doSomething(wrappedCallback
    dummyForStackFrame(key)
```