# Python: Pass extra arguments to callable

Tags: python, function, callable

I have the following python code:

```py
import networkx as nx 

def cost(i, j, d, value1, value2):
    # some operation involving all these values
    return cost


# graph is a networkx graph
# src, dst are integers
# cost is a callable that is passed 3 values automatically i.e. src, dst and d 
# d is a dictionary of edge weights
path = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, src, dst, weight=cost)
```

Now I want to pass two values `value1` and `value2` to the `cost` function.

The `networkx` documentation says the `weight` can be a callable that accepts exactly 3 arguments. But i need `value1` and `value2` for calculations. How can this be done?

**Edit**
The solution using functools works well. However, my function is in a class as follows:

```
import networkx as nx 
import functools
class Myclass:
    def cost(self, i, j, d, value2):
        # some operation involving all these values
        # also need self


    # graph is a networkx graph
    # src, dst are integers
    # cost is a callable that is passed 3 values automatically i.e. src, dst and d 
    # d is a dictionary of edge weights
    # path = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, src, dst, cost)
    cost_partial = functools.partial(cost, self=self, value2=5)
    path = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, src, dst, cost_partial)
```

Using this approach, `nx.dijkstra_path` insists upon assigning `src` to `self`. Thus the interpreter complains that `self` is assigned multiple values.
I need self for calculating the cost.

Comment: where would those values come from? if they are known and won't change for all of the function calls why not make them global variables?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Because global variables are frowned upon since they tend to lead to a messy code, and are (very) rarely the correct solution

Comment: @DeepSpace frowned upon by who? the python elder gods? it all depends on how big of a script you're making ...

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I'm really not going to try and "convince" you why global variables are a bad idea.

Comment: @DeepSpace good because stackoverflow is not a place for opinions

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Nor for bad advices...

Comment: @DeepSpace i wasn't giving advice to use global variables i was asking if the values are changing as the function is called again and again, which could invalidate some answers given here...

Comment: `self` seems to be undefined in the call to `functools.partial`.

Comment: Got it thanks. self is implicitly passed. No need to pass it separately.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite by who? By most experienced developers. As one example, a little company called [google](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#25-global-variables), but I'm sure they don't know what they're doing...

Comment: @strotter did you seriously just comment on a 2 year old post for that

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Information has a long life :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You just need a function that wraps `cost`. A quick way is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
import functools

def cost(i, j, d, value1, value2):
    'Example function'
    return i, j, d, value1, value2

# This makes a new function which takes all parameters of `cost` except those 
# you've already passed. Here I'm going to set value1 and value2 to 1 and 2 
# respectively.
cost_partial = functools.partial(cost, value1=1, value2=2)

# A new function that only accepts the 3 args i, j, d
cost_partial('i', 'j', 'd')  # --> ('i', 'j', 'd', 1, 2)

# use as
path = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, src, dst, weight=cost_partial)
```

Comment: Just to confirm that this solution worked like a charm for me in a similar case, trying to pass a fourth parameter to the filter_edge callable of the networkx.classes.function.subgraph_view(G, filter_node, filter_edge) function in networkx.   Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This depends largely on the meaning on the meaning of `value1` and `value2`. I would suggest adding a wrapper callable by networkx:

```
def cost_wrapper(i, j, d):
    value1 = 0  # set values as needed
    value2 = 1
    return cost(i, j, d, value1, value2)
```

And provide it to networkx:

```
path = nx.dijkstra_path(graph, src, dst, weight=cost_wrapper)
```

Or simply make them global variables, not arguments.