# Reading class method definition - what is Callable?

Tags: python-3.x, callable, open3d

I am relatively new to python, and I started to read the docs when using packages, but I'm having a hard time understanding some of it:

`post_to_main_thread(self: open3d.cpu.pybind.visualization.gui.Application, arg0: open3d::visualization::gui::Window, arg1: Callable[[], None]) → None`

the only thing here that I don't understand is the `arg1` with that callable, and I can't find an explanation on it at the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

So [`post_to_main_thread()`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.gui.Application.html#open3d.visualization.gui.Application.post_to_main_thread) is a method that takes 3 arguments (inputs/variables) and returns `None`.

Because it's a method (a function associated with a class, not just a standalone function) the first argument, `self`, refers to the instance of the class that the function is part of.

The other two arguments are passed within the function parentheses, as expected with a standalone function. So a call might look like this:

```py
instance_name = open3d.visualization.gui.Application(...)
instance_name.post_to_main_thread(arg1, arg2)
```

`arg1` should be of type `open3d::visualization::gui::Window`. This is an instance of the class [`open3d.visualization.gui.Window()`](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.visualization.gui.Window.html#open3d.visualization.gui.Window).

`arg2` should be of type `Callable()`. This describes a number of built-ins that you can find details about [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable). To quote:

> The subscription syntax must always be used with exactly two values: the argument list and the return type. The argument list must be a list of types or an ellipsis; the return type must be a single type.

So in this case the type should be `Callable[[], None]`, which means this should be a function that takes no input and returns `None`. Carrying on from our previous example, you'd pass this as an argument like so:

```py
def my_callable:
   print('Hello, World!')
   return

instance_name.post_to_main_thread(arg1, my_callable)
```

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Ok, now I get it much better, I just wasn't familiar with that callable existence, thanks.
So, if I want `my_callable:` to receive an argument and print, can I do it?

Comment: You can't pass arguments, but you can [wrap your callable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52077608/6144626) in another callable in which your arguments are defined.