# passing arguments to a callback function in Python

Tags: python, callback, arguments

I want to know the syntax for passing arguments to a callback function.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys,os,time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess

flag_callback=True

def Callback(channel,port_nb,dist_user,dist_ip):
        global flag_callback
        flag_callback=False
        print('Button Pushed. SSH Tunnel open on port: \"{}\" until reboot.'.format(port_nb))
        bashCommand = "nohup ssh -NR {}:localhost:22 {}@{}".format(port_nb,dist_user,dist_ip)
        subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(),
                stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'),
                stderr=open('logfile.log', 'a'),
                preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
                )

def main():
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
                port_nb=sys.argv[1]
        else:
                port_nb='2222'

        if len(sys.argv) > 2:
                dist_user=sys.argv[2]
        else:
                dist_user='martin'

        if len(sys.argv) > 3:
                dist_ip = sys.argv[3]
        else:
                dist_ip='192.168.11.111'
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback = Callback(port_nb,dist_user,dist_ip), bouncetime = 1000)
        try:
                while(flag_callback):
                        time.sleep(1)
        except:
                pass

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

But it's not working... :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./OnPushButton_PULLUP.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "./OnPushButton_PULLUP.py", line 47, in main
    GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, callback = Callback(port_nb,dist_user,dist_ip), bouncetime = 1000)
TypeError: Callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dist_ip'
```

I missed sth but I don't understand what...I took a look right [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks) but still stuck at this point :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Comment: This question is too dense to be helpful. Use a minimal example. I have this same question but the specifics are too thick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual solution for this scenario is to use `functools.partial()`. See this article for one explanation with examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/partial-functions-python/

Answer (score 1):

Okay I managed by doing this :

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.FALLING, lambda channel,tmp_port=port_nb,tmp_user=dist_user,tmp_ip=dist_ip:Callback(channel,tmp_port,tmp_user,tmp_ip), bouncetime = 1000)
```