# Passing an argument to a callback

Tags: python, callback

I have been having a bit of trouble with `add_word_listener` from the keyboard module. If I have a function that accepts a callback as an argument, how can I pass an argument to the callback? For example, here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
import keyboard

stopKey = "Windows"


def test(arg):
    print(arg)

keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", test("Hello World!"))

running = True
while running:
    if keyboard.is_pressed(stopKey):
        running = False
```

`add_word_listener` is a function that has 2 required arguments, the text that it listens for, and a callback. On the keyboard docs page, the callback argument is described as "an argument-less function to be invoked each time the word is typed." So does that mean that there is no way for me to pass an argument to the `test` function within `add_word_listener`? The code only works when we remove the argument and just have keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", test). If this is the only way to do it, is there a better way to pass a function with an argument here instead of creating a lot of specific functions? i.e. instead of creating functions like

```
def printhi():
    print("hi")
    
def printhello():
    print("hello")
```

each time I want to use `add_word_listener`?

Comment: Which keyboard module? Is it [this one](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)?

Comment: One way: `keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", lambda: test("Hello World!"))` which creates an argument-less anonymous callback function that calls the other one that requires one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*martineau* mentioned lambda as a solution

```
keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", lambda: test("Hello World!"))
```

another is `functools.partial`

```
keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", functools.partial(test, "Hello World!"))
```

You can even create a class with a `__call__` method instead of the function

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __call__(self):
        print(self.arg)

keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", Test("Hello World!"))
```

That last one is useful if you want to keep some extra state. Just as a made-up example, if you wanted to record when the callback was made you could do

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
    def __call__(self):
        self.called_at = time.time()
        print(self.arg)

test = Test("Hello world")
keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", test)
```

Comment: very well explained. I've never messed with __ call __ before but this was easy to understand and gave me a way to pass state to a callback function - cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I like both of the solutions above.  If lambdas scare you, you can also use an extra function.

```
def my_callback():
    test("hello")

keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", my_callback)
```

You can even write more generic code like this:

```
def add_my_word_listener(word, callback_word):
    def my_callback():
        test(callback_word)
    keyboard.add_word_listener(word, my_callback)

add_my_word_listener("hi", "hello")
add_my_word_listener("ciao", "goodbye")
```