# Passing additional arguments to a callback object that only takes 1

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, overloading, keyword-argument

So I am working on a little project and I am using the websocket client library and in order to create a `WebSocketApp` object which handles a websocket connection you instantiate the object with something like

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(uri, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_ping=on_ping)
```

now I have a function named `on_message` which is the callback function (object?) that handles the incoming messages, or rather what to do with them, and is called on by the `ws` object I created, when a full message comes in (obviously).   `on_message` is defined as the callback when a `WebSocketApp` object is instantiated.

on_message is something like this

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)
```

what I would like is something like this:

```
def on_message(ws, message, someList)
    somelist.append(message)
```

I can of course use a global variable to reference the object I want to update (in this example a list) but it doesn't seem like the right way to do it and it would be nice if I could pass a reference to the object I want to update when initializing a `WebSocketApp` object, with something like:

```
ws = websock.WebSocketApp(uri, on_message=on_message(ref_to_Obj), on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close)
```

But obviously that doesn't work because I get a `TypeError: on_message() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'message' and objRef'` error.

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this.  Subclassing comes to mind but not sure how I would accomplish it that way either.  Looking at the source for the `WebSocketApp` it says that it has 2 arguments, 1) the `WebSocketApp` class itself and 2) the utf-8 data received from the server.  I never pass these along and I assume the library just passes those references out when it creates them, but how could I overload this to include additional arguments?  First thing that comes to mind is to overload with *args or **kwargs but again not sure how to implement that.  I asked before and a lambda function was suggested but I couldn't figure how to get that to work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to ["partially apply"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) the function. That can be done using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

ws = websock.WebSocketApp(uri, on_message=partial(on_message, someList=ref_to_Obj))
```

`partial` takes a function and arguments (I'm using a keyword argument here), and returns a *new* function that has the partially applied information passed already.

The "poor man's" version of this would to just use a `lambda`:

```
ws = websock.WebSocketApp(uri, on_message=lambda ws, msg: on_message(ws, msg, ref_to_Obj))
```

`partial` should be preferred though, as it maintains meta-data from the original function, which can be useful.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!!  See I couldn't get the lambda version to work no matter what I did, it's still giving me issues for some reason.

Comment: So the lambda way of doing this doesn't seem to work, it never makes it to the function.  I am going to try the functools method now.

Comment: @user1884295 Both ways are nearly identical, and shouldn't cause what you're describing. They should behave exactly the same as before, just closing over an extra argument. I'd check for connection issues first.

Comment: Neverminded I got partial to work, but lambda is giving me issues so thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1884295 Out of curiosity, what's the issue? Like I said, they should perform identically.

Comment: So if I add (1)a positional, (2)a variable length argument, (3)positional and variable length argument, (4) keyword argument, (5) positional and keyword argument to the function definition, it just doesn't enter the function at all for some reason.  Maybe im doing something wrong?  I'm testing on on_open because that only takes one argument (not including the one I want to pass) so originally I had `def on_open(ws):` but i also tried `def on_open(ws, *arg):`, `def on_open(*arg):`, `def on_open(ws, **kwarg):`, `def on_open(ws, **kwarg):` none which worked.  1st line is a print it never reached