# Add second argument to ThreadedWebsocketManager function

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, arguments, cryptocurrency

I have a function that makes different dictionaries:

```
def get_dic():
    dic = {}
    for interval in intervals:
        for symbol in symbols:
            dic = {(symbol, interval, 'high'): [], (symbol, interval, 'low'): [], (symbol, interval, 'close'): []}
    historical(dic)
```

```
Then I have a function that starts the ThreadedWebsocketManager.start_multiplex_socket like this:
    twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
    twm.start()

    for interval in intervals:
        streams = ['btcusdt@kline_' + interval, 'ethusdt@kline_' + interval]
        twm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=add_new_data_values, streams=streams)
    twm.join()
```

Now this function calls the function add_new_data_values with the standard argument msg but I'd like to add the argument dic to it so I can use the dic retrieved from the get_dic function, however when I try this it gives the error "add_new_data_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dic'".:

```
def add_new_data_values(msg, dic):
    candle = msg['data']['k']
```

So what I'm asking is: how do I add this dic argument to the function? It has to do something with this line I think, but I don't know how to change it:

```
twm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=add_new_data_values, streams=streams)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partial from functools`

For your case `partial(add_new_data_values, dic=your_parameter)`

You can look for another example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323408/passing-additional-arguments-to-a-callback-object-that-only-takes-1).