# Adding extra parameters to a function which uses arguments as input

Tags: python, pynput

I have a function which is run when a key is pressed, to do this I use this code:

```
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

However the function on_press, needs some extra arguments. It's defined as this on_press(*args, x). How would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, how to pass an argument to a function pointer parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783211/python-how-to-pass-an-argument-to-a-function-pointer-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `lambda` function:

```
def on_press(event, arg1, arg2):
    ...

with Listener(on_press=lambda event: on_press(event, arg1=val1, arg2=val2)) as listener:
        listener.join()
```